# How to install xfontsel on Fedora 13? Any alternative?

Tags: fedora, xorg, fonts

I need xfontsel to select right font for xterm. But its not installed. I tried `yum` but it returned

> Warning: No matches found for: xfontsel 
>   No Matches found

I googled for xfontsel source code to compile myself but didn't get any link for that.

1. How can I install xfontsel on Fedora 13?
2. Its not installed by default and neither it is available in `yum` repo. So does this mean Fedora will not include it anymore? Why?
3. Any alternative to xfontsel? I tried `xlsfonts` but it does not give preview of fonts.

Thanks for your time and help.

### Edit

```
$ su -c "yum install xorg-x11-apps.i686"
```

This did the trick on my Fedora 13.

Comment: "yum install /usr/bin/xfontsel" (or perhaps just "/bin/fontsel") would have worked too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find out which package ships a given binary under Fedora like this:

```
yum provides "*bin/xfontsel"
```

however this only works if you know the name and directory of the executable. Indeed for xfontsel it is xorg-x11-utils as already stated by Michael:

```
$ yum provides /usr/bin/xfontsel
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, presto, refresh-packagekit
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * fedora: mirror.nl.as6453.net
 * livna: ftp-stud.fht-esslingen.de
 * rpmfusion-free: mirror.telepoint.bg
 * rpmfusion-free-updates: mirror.telepoint.bg
 * rpmfusion-nonfree: mirror.telepoint.bg
 * rpmfusion-nonfree-updates: mirror.telepoint.bg
 * updates: mirror.nl.as6453.net
xorg-x11-apps-7.4-13.fc13.i686 : X.Org X11 applications
Repo        : fedora
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/xfontsel



xorg-x11-apps-7.4-14.fc13.i686 : X.Org X11 applications
Repo        : updates
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/xfontsel



xorg-x11-apps-7.4-14.fc13.i686 : X.Org X11 applications
Repo        : installed
Matched from:
Other       : Provides-match: /usr/bin/xfontsel
```

Comment: You say it's in `xorg-x11-utils` yet in the output we see `xorg-x11-apps`. Why the difference?

Answer (score 2):

It's not necessarily in its own package, and it's not necessarily in a package named `xfontsel`. [This site](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/11442108/dir/fedora_6/com/xorg-x11-utils-7.1-2.fc6.x86_64.rpm.html) leads me to believe it's part of **`xorg-x11-utils`**, so installing that should work

Comment: It looks like it's part of `xorg-x11-apps` now (Fedora 21).

Answer (score 1):

Besides the above mentioned binary rpm's for Fedora, the xfontsel source code is available from X.Org at http://www.x.org/releases/individual/app/xfontsel-1.0.3.tar.bz2

Comment: Thanks a lot alanc. I googled for the source code but didn't find it. Really appreciated!